# Changing the 'body' element's background image smoothly with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, background-image, slideshow

I am new to JS and I am attempting to transition the `body{background:;}` image using a simple JS script.  Instead of stacking div's on top of each other and then changing their `z-index`, I wanted come up with a more simple solution, utilizing the CSS `background-size:cover` attribute.  Using the CSS attribute seems to scale the background image better (I am a newbie to I could wrong and naive) than when using:

```
$(window).resize(function() {};
```

My question is, how do I use the below code to better transition between images?  I would like to animate the transitions, but since I am not using stacked div's I simply don't know how.  There is currently a blank between picture transitions.  I attempted to pre-load the images but that didn't solve the issue either.

JavaScript:

```
function slideShow() {

var images = ['http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/fantasy_space-wide.jpg', 'http://phandroid.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/rainbow-nebula.jpg']

    setInterval(function(){

        document.body.style.backgroundImage="url('"+images[0]+"')";

        var firstValue = images.shift();
        images.push(firstValue);


    }, 5000);

}

slideShow();
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background:#000 no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/dclappert/pen/yqGob/

Answer (score 3):

I know you mention javascript here, but have you considered a CSS3 solution? Transitions provide an easy way of doing this.

An example here: http://jsfiddle.net/7eqsy2ug/ may be what you are looking for... You could also try fading the opacity if you want a smoother transition.

A JavaScript alternative is: http://rewish.github.io/jquery-bgswitcher/

Code from JS Fiddle using your JS:

```
body {
background:#000 no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;    
transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
```

}

Comment: I like this way, but transitioning _background-image_ is non-standard CSS3 so not implemented in FF or IE, may become standardised in CSS4

Comment: Indeed, you are correct. It only allows colours which I am using on my own website. Hopefully they will include this feature as it is a bit of a cludge to work around.


In this scenario, it may be better to use two <div> and change the opacity between the two or use the pure javascript approach.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help guys.  I will work on implementing one of the two solutions.  It's a shame that the CSS3 solution is not cross browser optimized.  It provides the right results, but is not supported in most browsers for this purpose as mentioned.